# Total up values of Dynamic column and apply formula in a new column

Tags: amazon-athena, ansi-sql

I have a below table structure :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `samplecontrolid`(
  `controlId` string, 
  `status` string, 
 )
```

Sample Data :

```
controlid       status  
CloudTrail.1    PASSED      
CloudTrail.1    PASSED      
CloudTrail.1    PASSED      
CloudTrail.1    PASSED  
CloudTrail.1    FAILED  
CloudTrail.1    FAILED  
IAM.8           PASSED  
IAM.8           PASSED      
IAM.8           FAILED      
IAM.8           FAILED  
IAM.8           FAILED      
IAM.8           FAILED
```

I want to count number of passed and failed for each ControlID:

Query i have written:

```
SELECT
   ControlId
  ,sum(case Status when 'PASSED' then 1 else 0 end) Passed
  ,sum(case Status when 'FAILED' then 1 else 0 end) Failed
 from samplecontrolid
 group by ControlId
```

Output:

```
ControlId    Passed Failed
CloudTrail.1    4   2
IAM.4           4   3
IAM.8           2   4
CIS3.2          5   0
```

Now, I want to have Total Column which Sum up Passed / Failed Value. Since Passed / Failed column value is generated on the fly , i cannot directly apply Sum function on these columns. How i can add up these values on the fly.
Like below :

```
ControlId    Passed Failed  Total
CloudTrail.1    4   2        6 
IAM.4           4   3        7
IAM.8           2   4        6
CIS3.2          5   0        5
```

Finally, Once Total value is calculated. I need another column calculating the percentage.

```
Percentage formula =  Passed / Total * 100
Example for CloudTrail.1 = 4/6 * 100 = 66.66
```

Final Output :

```
ControlId    Passed Failed  Total  Percentage
CloudTrail.1    4   2        6       66.66
IAM.4           4   3        7       57.14
IAM.8           2   4        6       33.33
CIS3.2          5   0        5       100
```

Comment: The syntax you've posted is *not* SQL Server, check your tags!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include Athena. Added now + Plus ANSI SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for as second pass

**Example**

```
SELECT  ControlId
       ,sum(case Status when 'PASSED' then 1 else 0 end) Passed
       ,sum(case Status when 'FAILED' then 1 else 0 end) Failed
       ,sum(1) Total
       ,avg( case when Status='PASSED' then 100.0 else 0.0 end) Pct
 from samplecontrolid
 group by ControlId
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: It returns me Zero for all pct

Comment: @Bokambo Did you include the decimal .0 ?  Also, originally I has proper case Passed vs PASSED.    Perhaps you are case sensitive

Comment: What does Sum(1) means here ?

Comment: @Bokambo Essentially the same as count(*)

Comment: How we can use variable (pct) values to calculate another value when i use pct it says it cannot be recognized. I have a new column "threshold" which has some percentage values, i want to compare pct value with threshold and if pct value is greater than or equal to threshold value it should say "Pass" else " Fail" in new column.

Comment: @Bokambo Not 100% clear on what you are looking for, but you can't reference a derived column (unless it comes from a sub-query or cross apply) ... but you can  CASE WHEN avg( case when Status='PASSED' then 100.0 else 0.0 end) >= threshold then 'Good' else  'Bad' end

Comment: Can you include this - CASE WHEN avg( case when Status='PASSED' then 100.0 else 0.0 end) >= threshold then 'Good' else 'Bad' end in above example query you posted, it gives me error when i am trying to include in the above query.

Comment: @Bokambo Here is a dbFiddle.  I don't know where you are getting THRESHOLD so I dropped in a hard value of 50   ... >> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5b77651abc99fa6f064a3cf4571cf5a8

Comment: I see in my case "Threshold" is varchar because it contains percentage value like "90%" so it is getting error because left hand  side is double. How we can fix it ?

Comment: Instead of doing sum(1) total, I want to sum only passed and failed status, Sum(1) is summing all the status count. There are other status as well. How to sumup only passed and failed status ?

Comment: @Bokambo  Simple  sum(case Status in ('PASSED','FAILED') then 1 else 0 end)

Comment: @Bokambo Or you can add a WHERE Status in ('PASSED','FAILED')

Comment: @Bokambo The WHERE is the better way to go if you have Status other than PASSED and FAILED

Comment: I would do count(*) instead of sum(1), to avoid confusing people.

Comment: Is it really that confusing ?   Besides, I save two whole characters  :)